# How to find an issue in android application using debug tools?

Tags: java, android

My android application crashed with the following stack. How to find the real issue and fix it?
What if in debug perspective after application crashes is automatically opens window "Source not found" and button "Edit Source Lookup Path...". How to inspect which line causing  problem?

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1879    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1980 
    ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 122    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1146  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4340    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

LogCat shows following errors:

```
12-07 20:10:52.803: W/dalvikvm(831): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/appspot/Gmaps_over_netActivity; (27)
12-07 20:10:52.803: W/dalvikvm(831): Link of class 'Lcom/appspot/Gmaps_over_netActivity;' failed
12-07 20:10:58.118: W/ActivityManager(87): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-07 20:10:58.955: W/ActivityManager(87): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{410f8a38 com.appspot/.Gmaps_over_netActivity}
```

What seems to be a problem?

Comment: is this the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

The "Source not found" and "Edit source lookup paths" messages/buttons usually come up when you get a crash. It basically means that your program tried to find code that didn't exist.

It looks like you get a crash when your program first launches so try setting a breakpoint by doubleclicking the line where your onCreate() starts. That will cause the program to stop at that point and you can "skip over" or "step into" each line of code and find your problem.

Here is a link that will tell you more about debugging in Eclipse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSitNPAExg

Answer (score 1):

you can double click on the error lines where line numbers are written...it will take you to the code where this error is occurring..

a better idea is to debug...

of if you want to run the app the add logs ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html ) and check DDMS.

Answer (score 1):

Run your app in debug mode and open the LogCat view. This will give you a more detailed stack trace.